# Xamarin NavigationPage for some pages not all

Tags: xamarin, navigation

I saw a lot apps that their first page doesn't have NavigationPage bar but rest pages have.
I wanna know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false" in the first page in your project. Such as:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="AppTest.PageTest" NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True">

</ContentPage>
```

The default value of is true, so the rest page will have the NavigationBar.

You can also do this in the page.cs with the code `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);`